# How to set request to a radio group if it has not been checked?

Tags: android

I have set onclick event on a button. If the radio buttons of a radio group is not selected then I try to focus that radio group. Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        int selectedId = radiogroup .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId !=-1){
           RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
           String myString = radioButton .getText().toString();
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myradioRG.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats that earlyafternoon.... While you put selected item in selectedId variable .

I think maybe you must write

```
 if(selectedId != -1)
```

You are also requesting focus on the wrong radioGroup i think !!! The rue code is:

```
 radiogroup.requestFocus();
 radiogroup.requestFocusFromTouch()
```

Comment: I am sorry my mistake. it should be selectedID. But i am not able to set focus in radio group.

Comment: What you mean exactly by focus ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: When I hit the button and if no radio buttons were selected in my radio group then the view should set focus on that radio group. But no need to worry, I have got the solution. Anyway thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Share the answer im eager to know ;)

Comment: I just forgot to set focusable and setFocusableInTouchMode to true. After i set them to true i just used requestFocus(int direction) to my radio group.;

Comment: I pointed in my answer. Look at edit time its before your previous comment ;)